# Como agrupar y sumar un elemento de una lista con LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo esta lista que viene de un rest

```
"distribuidos": [
      {
        "tipo_comida_id": 10197,
        "fecha_solicitud": "2019-05-15T00:00:00",
        "total_pedido": 25,
        "consumido": 0,
        "consumo_justificado": 0,
        "total_consumido": 0,
        "Id": 16
      },
      {
        "tipo_comida_id": 10197,
        "fecha_solicitud": "2019-05-15T00:00:00",
        "total_pedido": 25,
        "consumido": 0,
        "consumo_justificado": 0,
        "total_consumido": 0,
        "Id": 17
      },
      {
        "tipo_comida_id": 10197,
        "fecha_solicitud": "2019-05-15T00:00:00",
        "total_pedido": 25,
        "consumido": 0,
        "consumo_justificado": 0,
        "total_consumido": 0,
        "Id": 18
      },
      {
        "tipo_comida_id": 10197,
        "fecha_solicitud": "2019-05-15T00:00:00",
        "total_pedido": 25,
        "consumido": 0,
        "consumo_justificado": 0,
        "total_consumido": 0,
        "Id": 19
      }
```

lo que quiero obtener es la suma de **total_pedido** en este caso me debe dar 100, sin embargo no lo logro.

Tengo este codigo:

```
var list = await distribucionService.GetTotales(fecha, tipoComidaId);

var list2 = list.Where(s => s.fecha_solicitud == fecha && s.tipo_comida_id == tipoComidaId);

var aux = list2.Select(s => new { Id = s.Id, total_pedido = list2.Sum(d => d.total_pedido)}).First();
```

Sin embargo esto me devuelve

```
    "distribuidos": [
      {
        "Id": 16,
        "total_pedido": 100
      },
      {
        "Id": 17,
        "total_pedido": 100
      },
      {
        "Id": 18,
        "total_pedido": 100
      },
      {
        "Id": 19,
        "total_pedido": 100
      }
```

lo que quiero obtener es:

```
"distribuidos": [
          {
            "Id": 16,
            "total_pedido": 100
          }
```

Me parece que hay que usar **GroupBy** para llegar al resultado, pero no tengo idea como hacerlo.

**Como podria hacerlo?**

Comment: si vas a sumar no puedes poner el Id como parte de los datos porque eso no se puede agrupar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes definir un campo agrupado con otro que no se puede agrupar como es el `Id`, este identifica cada item no se agrupa salvo que tomes el First() o Last() Id

El total se obtiene simplemente

```
var total_pedido = list2.Sum(d => d.total_pedido);
```

Salvo que crees la entidad anonima con el primer id y la suma

```
var aux = new { 
       Id = list2.First().Id, 
       total_pedido = list2.Sum(d => d.total_pedido)
     };
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió tu respuesta.